# cron task cakephp ovh

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-3.0

I have few Shell scripts in my Cakephp 3 app. I'd like to create a cron task to execute my shells once per hour.
I tried to set up cron with SSH but it doesn't work on my new OVH server.

Here is the command I tried :

```
crontab -e 0 * * * * cd /home/site/public_html/app && bin/cake myshell
```

It doesn't work. 
Have you every tried cron task on OVH servers with Cakephp?

Thanks!

**EDIT : Solution found, command is executed in a bash file using OVH admin panel.**

Comment: If you already created myshell than you should add `/home/site/public_html/app/bin/cake myshell` to your crontab file.

Comment: I have an error related to sudoers. Is it possible to put this command into a php file and execute it via OVH panel?

Comment: "I have an error related to sudoers" Is it related to what you're trying to achieve? If so: [edit] it in the question

Comment: Ok first message is edited

Comment: If you try just running `crontab -e`, does it open the crontab editor?

Comment: Thanks for your message. I've edited my first post, the solution was found